Debugging REShAPE software mex and nvcc issue
I am running this software called REShAPE on Windows 10 using Matlab 2019b and VS Studio 2017. although I get this error:

MATLAB: > In vl_compilenn>activate_nvcc (line 768)
MATLAB: In vl_compilenn (line 300)
MATLAB: In segmfunc (line 63)]
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   CUDA: using NVCC 'C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\nvcc' (100205).
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   CUDA: determining GPU compute capability (use the 'CudaArch' option to override)
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   CUDA: cannot determine the capabilities of the installed GPU and/or CUDA; falling back to default
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   CUDA: NVCC architecture string: '-gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"'.
MATLAB: Warning: Support for toolboxdir('distcomp') will be removed in a future release.  Use toolboxdir('parallel') instead.]
MATLAB: > In toolboxdir (line 49)
MATLAB: In vl_compilenn (line 383)
MATLAB: In segmfunc (line 63)]
MATLAB: vl_compilenn: * Compiler and linker configurations *
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   intermediate build products directory: C:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\mex\.build
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX files: C:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\mex/
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   Base options: -DENABLE_GPU -DENABLE_DOUBLE -O -DNDEBUG
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX CXX: -R2018a -D__SSSE3__
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX CXXFLAGS:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX CXXOPTIMFLAGS:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX LINK: -R2018a -lmwblas -L"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\lib\x64" -lcudart -lcublas -lgpu
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX LINK LDFLAGS:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX LINK LDOPTIMFLAGS:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX LINK LINKLIBS: gdiplus.lib
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX CUDA: -R2018a
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX CUDA CXXFLAGS:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   MEX CUDA CXXOPTIMFLAGS:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   NVCC: -D_FORCE_INLINES --std=c++11 -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\parallel\gpu\extern\include" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --compiler-options=/MD
MATLAB: vl_compilenn: * Reading images *
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   vl_imreadjpeg enabled
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   image library: gdiplus
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   image library compile flags:
MATLAB: vl_compilenn:   image library link flags: gdiplus.lib
MATLAB: vl_compilenn: NVCC CC: "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\nvcc" -c -o -v "C:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj" "C:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\src\bits\data.cu" -DENABLE_GPU -DENABLE_DOUBLE -O -DNDEBUG -D_FORCE_INLINES --std=c++11 -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\parallel\gpu\extern\include" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --compiler-options=/MD
MATLAB: nvcc fatal   : '-DNDEBUG': expected a number
MATLAB: Command "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.1\bin\nvcc" -c -o -v "C:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\mex\.build\bits\data.obj" "C:\Users\gelme\REShAPE\Segmentation\matconvnet\matlab\src\bits\data.cu" -DENABLE_GPU -DENABLE_DOUBLE -O -DNDEBUG -D_FORCE_INLINES --std=c++11 -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\extern\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2019b\toolbox\parallel\gpu\extern\include" -gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" -gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\" --compiler-options=/MD  failed.

This seems to be an issue with the vl.compilenn.m showed in the image. It's still using nvcc when I am trying to use mex. How can I fix this issue that it's giving me in the image?
This is the code I currently have for vl.compilenn
function vl_compilenn(varargin)
%VL_COMPILENN Compile the MatConvNet toolbox.
%   
opts.continue         = false;
opts.enableGpu        = false;
opts.enableImreadJpeg = true;
opts.enableCudnn      = false;
opts.enableDouble     = true;
opts.imageLibrary = [] ;
opts.imageLibraryCompileFlags = {} ;
opts.imageLibraryLinkFlags = [] ;
opts.verbose          = 0;
opts.debug            = false;
opts.cudaMethod       = 'mex' ;
opts.cudaRoot         = [] ;
opts.cudaArch         = [] ;
opts.defCudaArch      = [...
  '-gencode=arch=compute_20,code=\"sm_20,compute_20\" '...
  '-gencode=arch=compute_30,code=\"sm_30,compute_30\"'];
opts.mexConfig        = '' ;
opts.mexCudaConfig    = '' ;
opts.cudnnRoot        = 'local/cudnn' ;
opts.preCompileFn       = [] ;

% <### Inserted by matconvnet_patch.py ###>
opts.mexFlags = {'-largeArrayDims'};

opts = vl_argparse(opts, varargin);

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                     Files to compile
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

arch = computer('arch') ;
check_compability(arch);
if isempty(opts.imageLibrary)
  switch arch
    case 'glnxa64', opts.imageLibrary = 'libjpeg' ;
    case 'maci64', opts.imageLibrary = 'quartz' ;
    case 'win64', opts.imageLibrary = 'gdiplus' ;
  end
end
if isempty(opts.imageLibraryLinkFlags)
  switch opts.imageLibrary
    case 'libjpeg', opts.imageLibraryLinkFlags = {'-ljpeg'} ;
    case 'quartz', opts.imageLibraryLinkFlags = {'-framework Cocoa -framework ImageIO'} ;
    case 'gdiplus', opts.imageLibraryLinkFlags = {'gdiplus.lib'} ;
  end
end

lib_src = {} ;
mex_src = {} ;

% Files that are compiled as CPP or CU depending on whether GPU support
% is enabled.
if opts.enableGpu, ext = 'cu' ; else ext='cpp' ; end
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['data.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['datamex.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnconv.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnfullyconnected.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnsubsample.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnpooling.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnnormalize.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnnormalizelp.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnbnorm.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnbias.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnbilinearsampler.' ext]) ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits',['nnroipooling.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnconv.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnconvt.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnpool.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnnormalize.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnnormalizelp.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnbnorm.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnbilinearsampler.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_nnroipool.' ext]) ;
mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_taccummex.' ext]) ;
switch arch
  case {'glnxa64','maci64'}
    % not yet supported in windows
    mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src',['vl_tmove.' ext]) ;
end

% CPU-specific files
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','impl','im2row_cpu.cpp') ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','impl','copy_cpu.cpp') ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','impl','tinythread.cpp') ;
lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','imread.cpp') ;

% GPU-specific files
if opts.enableGpu
  lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','impl','im2row_gpu.cu') ;
  lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','impl','copy_gpu.cu') ;
  lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','bits','datacu.cu') ;
  mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src','vl_cudatool.cu') ;
end

% cuDNN-specific files
if opts.enableCudnn
end

% Other files
if opts.enableImreadJpeg
  mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src', ['vl_imreadjpeg.' ext]) ;
  mex_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src', ['vl_imreadjpeg_old.' ext]) ;
  lib_src{end+1} = fullfile(root,'matlab','src', 'bits', 'impl', ['imread_' opts.imageLibrary '.cpp']) ;
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                   Setup CUDA toolkit
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

if opts.enableGpu
  opts.verbose && fprintf('%s: * CUDA configuration *\n', mfilename) ;

  % Find the CUDA Devkit
  if isempty(opts.cudaRoot), opts.cudaRoot = search_cuda_devkit(opts) ; end
  opts.verbose && fprintf('%s:\tCUDA: using CUDA Devkit ''%s''.\n', ...
                          mfilename, opts.cudaRoot) ;

  opts.nvccPath = fullfile(opts.cudaRoot, 'bin', 'nvcc') ;
  switch arch
    case 'win64', opts.cudaLibDir = fullfile(opts.cudaRoot, 'lib', 'x64') ;
    case 'maci64', opts.cudaLibDir = fullfile(opts.cudaRoot, 'lib') ;
    case 'glnxa64', opts.cudaLibDir = fullfile(opts.cudaRoot, 'lib64') ;
  end

  % Set the nvcc method as default for Win platforms
  if strcmp(arch, 'win64') && isempty(opts.cudaMethod)
    opts.cudaMethod = 'nvcc';
  end

  % Activate the CUDA Devkit
  cuver = activate_nvcc(opts.nvccPath) ;
  opts.verbose && fprintf('%s:\tCUDA: using NVCC ''%s'' (%d).\n', ...
                          mfilename, opts.nvccPath, cuver) ;

  % Set the CUDA arch string (select GPU architecture)
  if isempty(opts.cudaArch), opts.cudaArch = get_cuda_arch(opts) ; end
  opts.verbose && fprintf('%s:\tCUDA: NVCC architecture string: ''%s''.\n', ...
                          mfilename, opts.cudaArch) ;
end

if opts.enableCudnn
  opts.cudnnIncludeDir = fullfile(opts.cudnnRoot, 'include') ;
  switch arch
    case 'win64', opts.cudnnLibDir = fullfile(opts.cudnnRoot, 'lib', 'x64') ;
    case 'maci64', opts.cudnnLibDir = fullfile(opts.cudnnRoot, 'lib') ;
    case 'glnxa64', opts.cudnnLibDir = fullfile(opts.cudnnRoot, 'lib64') ;
  end
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                     Compiler options
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

% Build directories
flags.src_dir = fullfile(root, 'matlab', 'src') ;
flags.mex_dir = fullfile(root, 'matlab', 'mex') ;
flags.bld_dir = fullfile(flags.mex_dir, '.build');
if ~exist(fullfile(flags.bld_dir,'bits','impl'), 'dir')
  mkdir(fullfile(flags.bld_dir,'bits','impl')) ;
end

% BASE: Base flags passed to `mex` and `nvcc` always.
flags.base = {} ;
if opts.enableGpu, flags.base{end+1} = '-DENABLE_GPU' ; end
if opts.enableDouble, flags.base{end+1} = '-DENABLE_DOUBLE' ; end
if opts.enableCudnn
  flags.base{end+1} = '-DENABLE_CUDNN' ;
  flags.base{end+1} = ['-I"' opts.cudnnIncludeDir '"'] ;
end
if opts.verbose > 1, flags.base{end+1} = '-v' ; end
if opts.debug
  flags.base{end+1} = '-g' ;
  flags.base{end+1} = '-DDEBUG' ;
else
  flags.base{end+1} = '-O' ;
  flags.base{end+1} = '-DNDEBUG' ;
end

% MEX: Additional flags passed to `mex` for compiling C++
% code. CXX and CXXOPTIOM are passed directly to the encapsualted compiler.

% <### Changed by matconvnet_patch.py ###>
% flags.mex = {'-largeArrayDims'} ;
flags.mex = opts.mexFlags;

flags.cxx = {} ;
flags.cxxoptim = {} ;
if ~isempty(opts.mexConfig), flags.mex = horzcat(flags.mex, {'-f', opts.mexConfig}) ; end

% MEX: Additional flags passed to `mex` for compiling CUDA
% code. CXX and CXXOPTIOM are passed directly to the encapsualted compiler.

% <### Changed by matconvnet_patch.py ###>
% flags.mexcuda = {'-largeArrayDims'} ;
flags.mexcuda = opts.mexFlags;

flags.mexcuda_cxx = {} ;
flags.mexcuda_cxxoptim = {} ;
if ~isempty(opts.mexCudaConfig), flags.mexcuda = horzcat(flags.mexcuda, {'-f', opts.mexCudaConfig}) ; end

% MEX_LINK: Additional flags passed to `mex` for linking.

% <### Changed by matconvnet_patch.py ###>
% flags.mexlink = {'-largeArrayDims','-lmwblas'} ;
flags.mexlink = horzcat(opts.mexFlags, {'-lmwblas'});

flags.mexlink_ldflags = {} ;
flags.mexlink_ldoptimflags = {} ;
flags.mexlink_linklibs = {} ;

% NVCC: Additional flags passed to `nvcc` for compiling CUDA code.
flags.nvcc = {'-D_FORCE_INLINES', '--std=c++11', ...
  sprintf('-I"%s"',fullfile(matlabroot,'extern','include')), ...
  sprintf('-I"%s"',fullfile(toolboxdir('distcomp'),'gpu','extern','include')), ...
  opts.cudaArch} ;

switch arch
  case {'maci64','glnxa64'}
    flags.cxx{end+1} = '--std=c++11' ;
    flags.nvcc{end+1} = '--compiler-options=-fPIC' ;
    if ~opts.debug
      flags.cxxoptim = horzcat(flags.cxxoptim,'-mssse3','-ffast-math') ;
      flags.mexcuda_cxxoptim{end+1} = '--compiler-options=-mssse3,-ffast-math' ;
      flags.nvcc{end+1} = '--compiler-options=-mssse3,-ffast-math' ;
    end
  case 'win64'
    % Visual Studio 2015 does C++11 without futher switches
end

if opts.enableGpu
  flags.mexlink = horzcat(flags.mexlink, ...
    {['-L"' opts.cudaLibDir '"'], '-lcudart', '-lcublas'}) ;
  switch arch
    case {'maci64', 'glnxa64'}
      flags.mexlink{end+1} = '-lmwgpu' ;
    case 'win64'
      flags.mexlink{end+1} = '-lgpu' ;
  end
  if opts.enableCudnn
    flags.mexlink{end+1} = ['-L"' opts.cudnnLibDir '"'] ;
    flags.mexlink{end+1} = '-lcudnn' ;
  end
end

switch arch
  case {'maci64'}
    flags.mex{end+1} = '-cxx' ;
    flags.nvcc{end+1} = '--compiler-options=-mmacosx-version-min=10.10' ;
    [s,r] = system('xcrun -f clang++') ;
    if s == 0
      flags.nvcc{end+1} = sprintf('--compiler-bindir="%s"',strtrim(r)) ;
    end
    if opts.enableGpu
      flags.mexlink_ldflags{end+1} = sprintf('-Wl,-rpath -Wl,"%s"', opts.cudaLibDir) ;
    end
    if opts.enableGpu && opts.enableCudnn
      flags.mexlink_ldflags{end+1} = sprintf('-Wl,-rpath -Wl,"%s"', opts.cudnnLibDir) ;
    end

  case {'glnxa64'}
    flags.mex{end+1} = '-cxx' ;
    flags.mexlink{end+1} = '-lrt' ;
    if opts.enableGpu
      flags.mexlink_ldflags{end+1} = sprintf('-Wl,-rpath -Wl,"%s"', opts.cudaLibDir) ;
    end
    if opts.enableGpu && opts.enableCudnn
      flags.mexlink_ldflags{end+1} = sprintf('-Wl,-rpath -Wl,"%s"', opts.cudnnLibDir) ;
    end

  case {'win64'}
    % VisualC does not pass this even if available in the CPU architecture
    flags.mex{end+1} = '-D__SSSE3__' ;
    cl_path = fileparts(check_clpath()); % check whether cl.exe in path
    flags.nvcc{end+1} = '--compiler-options=/MD' ;
    % flags.nvcc{end+1} = sprintf('--compiler-bindir="%s"', cl_path) ;
end

if opts.enableImreadJpeg
  flags.mex = horzcat(flags.mex, opts.imageLibraryCompileFlags) ;
  flags.mexlink_linklibs = horzcat(flags.mexlink_linklibs, opts.imageLibraryLinkFlags) ;
end

if ~isempty(opts.preCompileFn)
  [opts, mex_src, lib_src, flags] = opts.preCompileFn(opts, mex_src, lib_src, flags) ;
end

% Compile intermediate object files
srcs = horzcat(lib_src,mex_src) ;
for i = 1:numel(horzcat(lib_src, mex_src))
  [~,~,ext] = fileparts(srcs{i}) ; ext(1) = [] ;
  objfile = toobj(flags.bld_dir,srcs{i});
  if strcmp(ext,'cu')
    if strcmp(opts.cudaMethod,'nvcc')
      nvcc_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
    else
      mexcuda_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
    end
  else
    mex_compile(opts, srcs{i}, objfile, flags) ;
  end
  assert(exist(objfile, 'file') ~= 0, 'Compilation of %s failed.', objfile);
end

% Link MEX files
for i = 1:numel(mex_src)
  objs = toobj(flags.bld_dir, [mex_src(i), lib_src]) ;
  mex_link(opts, objs, flags.mex_dir, flags) ;
end

% Reset path adding the mex subdirectory just created
vl_setupnn() ;

if strcmp(arch, 'win64') && opts.enableCudnn
  if opts.verbose(), fprintf('Copying CuDNN dll to mex folder.\n'); end
  copyfile(fullfile(opts.cudnnRoot, 'bin', '*.dll'), flags.mex_dir);
end

% Save the last compile flags to the build dir
if isempty(opts.preCompileFn)
  save(fullfile(flags.bld_dir, 'last_compile_opts.mat'), '-struct', 'opts');
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
%                                                    Utility functions
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function check_compability(arch)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('C++');
if isempty(cc)
  error(['Mex is not configured.'...
    'Run "mex -setup" to configure your compiler. See ',...
    'http://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers ', ...
    'for supported compilers for your platform.']);
end

switch arch
  case 'win64'
    clversion = str2double(cc.Version);
    if clversion < 14
      error('Unsupported VS C++ compiler, ver >=14.0 required (VS 2015).');
    end
  case 'maci64'
  case 'glnxa64'
  otherwise, error('Unsupported architecture ''%s''.', arch) ;
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function done = check_deps(opts, tgt, src)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
done = false ;
if ~iscell(src), src = {src} ; end
if ~opts.continue, return ; end
if ~exist(tgt,'file'), return ; end
ttime = dir(tgt) ; ttime = ttime.datenum ;
for i=1:numel(src)
  stime = dir(src{i}) ; stime = stime.datenum ;
  if stime > ttime, return ; end
end
fprintf('%s: ''%s'' already there, skipping.\n', mfilename, tgt) ;
done = true ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function objs = toobj(bld_dir, srcs)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
str = [filesep, 'src', filesep]; % NASTY. Do with regexp?
multiple = iscell(srcs) ;
if ~multiple, srcs = {srcs} ; end
objs = cell(1, numel(srcs));
for t = 1:numel(srcs)
  i = strfind(srcs{t},str);
  i = i(end); % last occurence of '/src/'
  objs{t} = fullfile(bld_dir, srcs{t}(i+numel(str):end)) ;
end
if ~multiple, objs = objs{1} ; end
objs = regexprep(objs,'.cpp$',['.' objext]) ;
objs = regexprep(objs,'.cu$',['.' objext]) ;
objs = regexprep(objs,'.c$',['.' objext]) ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function mex_compile(opts, src, tgt, flags)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
if check_deps(opts, tgt, src), return ; end
args = horzcat({'-c', '-outdir', fileparts(tgt), src}, ...
  flags.base, flags.mex, ...
  {['CXXFLAGS=$CXXFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.cxx)]}, ...
  {['CXXOPTIMFLAGS=$CXXOPTIMFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.cxxoptim)]}) ;
opts.verbose && fprintf('%s: MEX CC: %s\n', mfilename, strjoin(args)) ;
mex(args{:}) ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function mexcuda_compile(opts, src, tgt, flags)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
if check_deps(opts, tgt, src), return ; end
% Hacky fix: In glnxa64 MATLAB includes the -ansi option by default, which
% prevents -std=c++11 to work (an error?). This could be solved by editing the
% mex configuration file; for convenience, we take it out here by
% avoiding to append to the default flags.
glue = '$CXXFLAGS' ;
switch computer('arch')
  case {'glnxa64'}
    glue = '--compiler-options=-fexceptions,-fPIC,-fno-omit-frame-pointer,-pthread' ;
end
args = horzcat({'-c', '-outdir', fileparts(tgt), src}, ...
  flags.base, flags.mexcuda, ...
  {['CXXFLAGS=' glue ' ' strjoin(flags.mexcuda_cxx)]}, ...
  {['CXXOPTIMFLAGS=$CXXOPTIMFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.mexcuda_cxxoptim)]}) ;
opts.verbose && fprintf('%s: MEX CUDA: %s\n', mfilename, strjoin(args)) ;
mexcuda(args{:}) ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function nvcc_compile(opts, src, tgt, flags)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
if check_deps(opts, tgt, src), return ; end
nvcc_path = fullfile(opts.cudaRoot, 'bin', 'nvcc');
nvcc_cmd = sprintf('"%s" -c -o -v "%s" "%s" %s ', ...
                   nvcc_path, tgt, src, ...
                   strjoin(horzcat(flags.base,flags.nvcc)));
opts.verbose && fprintf('%s: NVCC CC: %s\n', mfilename, nvcc_cmd) ;
status = system(nvcc_cmd);
if status, error('Command %s failed.', nvcc_cmd); end;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function mex_link(opts, objs, mex_dir, flags)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
args = horzcat({'-outdir', mex_dir}, ...
  flags.base, flags.mexlink, ...
  {['LDFLAGS=$LDFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.mexlink_ldflags)]}, ...
  {['LDOPTIMFLAGS=$LDOPTIMFLAGS ' strjoin(flags.mexlink_ldoptimflags)]}, ...
  {['LINKLIBS=' strjoin(flags.mexlink_linklibs) ' $LINKLIBS']}, ...
  objs) ;
opts.verbose && fprintf('%s: MEX LINK: %s\n', mfilename, strjoin(args)) ;
mex(args{:}) ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function ext = objext()
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% Get the extension for an 'object' file for the current computer
% architecture
switch computer('arch')
  case 'win64', ext = 'obj';
  case {'maci64', 'glnxa64'}, ext = 'o' ;
  otherwise, error('Unsupported architecture %s.', computer) ;
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function cl_path = check_clpath()
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
% Checks whether the cl.exe is in the path (needed for the nvcc). If
% not, tries to guess the location out of mex configuration.
cc = mex.getCompilerConfigurations('c++');
cl_path = fullfile(cc.Location, 'VC', 'bin', 'amd64');
[status, ~] = system('cl.exe -help');
if status == 1
  % Add cl.exe to system path so that nvcc can find it.
  warning('CL.EXE not found in PATH. Trying to guess out of mex setup.');
  prev_path = getenv('PATH');
  setenv('PATH', [prev_path ';' cl_path]);
  status = system('cl.exe');
  if status == 1
    setenv('PATH', prev_path);
    error('Unable to find cl.exe');
  else
    fprintf('Location of cl.exe (%s) successfully added to your PATH.\n', ...
      cl_path);
  end
end

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
function paths = which_nvcc()
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
switch computer('arch')
  case 'win64'
    [~, paths] = system('where nvcc.exe');
    paths = strtrim(paths);
    paths = paths(strfind(paths, '.exe'));
  case {'maci64', 'glnxa64'}
    [~, paths] = system('which nvcc');
    paths = strtrim(paths) ;
end

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
function cuda_root = search_cuda_devkit(opts)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
% This function tries to to locate a working copy of the CUDA Devkit.

opts.verbose && fprintf(['%s:\tCUDA: searching for the CUDA Devkit' ...
                    ' (use the option ''CudaRoot'' to override):\n'], mfilename);

% Propose a number of candidate paths for NVCC
paths = {getenv('MW_NVCC_PATH')} ;
paths = [paths, which_nvcc()] ;
for v = {'5.5', '6.0', '6.5', '7.0', '7.5', '8.0', '8.5', '9.0', '9.5', '10.0'}
  switch computer('arch')
    case 'glnxa64'
      paths{end+1} = sprintf('/usr/local/cuda-%s/bin/nvcc', char(v)) ;
    case 'maci64'
      paths{end+1} = sprintf('/Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-%s/bin/nvcc', char(v)) ;
    case 'win64'
      paths{end+1} = sprintf('C:\\Program Files\\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\\CUDA\\v%s\\bin\\nvcc.exe', char(v)) ;
  end
end
paths{end+1} = sprintf('/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc') ;

% Validate each candidate NVCC path
for i=1:numel(paths)
  nvcc(i).path = paths{i} ;
  [nvcc(i).isvalid, nvcc(i).version] = validate_nvcc(paths{i}) ;
end
if opts.verbose
  fprintf('\t| %5s | %5s | %-70s |\n', 'valid', 'ver', 'NVCC path') ;
  for i=1:numel(paths)
    fprintf('\t| %5d | %5d | %-70s |\n', ...
            nvcc(i).isvalid, nvcc(i).version, nvcc(i).path) ;
  end
end

% Pick an entry
index = find([nvcc.isvalid]) ;
if isempty(index)
  error('Could not find a valid NVCC executable\n') ;
end
[~, newest] = max([nvcc(index).version]);
nvcc = nvcc(index(newest)) ;
cuda_root = fileparts(fileparts(nvcc.path)) ;

if opts.verbose
  fprintf('%s:\tCUDA: choosing NVCC compiler ''%s'' (version %d)\n', ...
          mfilename, nvcc.path, nvcc.version) ;
end

% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
function [valid, cuver]  = validate_nvcc(nvccPath)
% -------------------------------------------------------------------------
[status, output] = system(sprintf('"%s" --version', nvccPath)) ;
valid = (status == 0) ;
if ~valid
  cuver = 0 ;
  return ;
end
match = regexp(output, 'V(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)', 'match') ;
if isempty(match), valid = false ; return ; end
cuver = [1e4 1e2 1] * sscanf(match{1}, 'V%d.%d.%d') ;

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function cuver = activate_nvcc(nvccPath)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------

% Validate the NVCC compiler installation
[valid, cuver] = validate_nvcc(nvccPath) ;
if ~valid
  error('The NVCC compiler ''%s'' does not appear to be valid.', nvccPath) ;
end

% Make sure that NVCC is visible by MEX by setting the MW_NVCC_PATH
% environment variable to the NVCC compiler path
if ~strcmp(getenv('MW_NVCC_PATH'), nvccPath)
  warning('Setting the ''MW_NVCC_PATH'' environment variable to ''%s''', nvccPath) ;
  setenv('MW_NVCC_PATH', nvccPath) ;
end

% In some operating systems and MATLAB versions, NVCC must also be
% available in the command line search path. Make sure that this is%
% the case.
[valid_, cuver_] = validate_nvcc('nvcc') ;
if ~valid_ || cuver_ ~= cuver
  warning('NVCC not found in the command line path or the one found does not matches ''%s''.', nvccPath);
  nvccDir = fileparts(nvccPath) ;
  prevPath = getenv('PATH') ;
  switch computer
    case 'PCWIN64', separator = ';' ;
    case {'GLNXA64', 'MACI64'}, separator = ':' ;
  end
  setenv('PATH', [nvccDir separator prevPath]) ;
  [valid_, cuver_] = validate_nvcc('nvcc') ;
  if ~valid_ || cuver_ ~= cuver
    setenv('PATH', prevPath) ;
    error('Unable to set the command line path to point to ''%s'' correctly.', nvccPath) ;
  else
    fprintf('Location of NVCC (%s) added to your command search PATH.\n', nvccDir) ;
  end
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function cudaArch = get_cuda_arch(opts)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
opts.verbose && fprintf('%s:\tCUDA: determining GPU compute capability (use the ''CudaArch'' option to override)\n', mfilename);
try
  gpu_device = gpuDevice();
  arch = str2double(strrep(gpu_device.ComputeCapability, '.', ''));
  supparchs = get_nvcc_supported_archs(opts.nvccPath);
  [~, archi] = max(min(supparchs - arch, 0));
  arch_code = num2str(supparchs(archi));
  assert(~isempty(arch_code));
  cudaArch = ...
      sprintf('-gencode=arch=compute_%s,code=\\\"sm_%s,compute_%s\\\" ', ...
              arch_code, arch_code, arch_code) ;
catch
  opts.verbose && fprintf(['%s:\tCUDA: cannot determine the capabilities of the installed GPU and/or CUDA; ' ...
                      'falling back to default\n'], mfilename);
  cudaArch = opts.defCudaArch;
end

% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function archs = get_nvcc_supported_archs(nvccPath)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
switch computer('arch')
  case {'win64'}
    [status, hstring] = system(sprintf('"%s" --help',nvccPath));
  otherwise
    % fix possible output corruption (see manual)
    [status, hstring] = system(sprintf('"%s" --help < /dev/null',nvccPath)) ;
end
archs = regexp(hstring, '''sm_(\d{2})''', 'tokens');
archs = cellfun(@(a) str2double(a{1}), archs);
if status, error('NVCC command failed: %s', hstring); end;

% Force the use of x64 architecture in the mex command
if opts.enableGpu
  % If GPU is enabled, set the machine architecture explicitly to x64
  flags.mexcc = [flags.mexcc ' -v COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /machine:x64"'];
else
  % For CPU-only, also ensure x64 architecture
  flags.mexcc = [flags.mexcc ' -v COMPFLAGS="$COMPFLAGS /machine:x64"'];
end

% Ensure that no ARM64 libraries are used; focus on x64 libraries only.
flags.link = [flags.link ' -L"C:\path\to\x64\libs"']; % Ensure correct x64 library paths
flags.lib = [flags.lib ' -llibmx' ' -llibmex' ' -llibmat']; % Ensure correct x64 libraries are linked


see here. The -O before -DNDEBUG needs a number. Perhaps try changing the line flags.base{end+1} = '-O' ; to use -O3.

@rinkert Hi! I tried that but am still getting this: MATLAB: nvcc fatal   : Unsupported gpu architecture 'compute_20' not to sure how to overcome it. What do you think?

You can check which architecture your gpu has, and only compile for that architecture. Replace compute_20 and compute_30 by e.g. compute_86.

@rinkert I tried this and it led to this error: MATLAB: Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.35.32217.1 for ARM64: Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.: tmpxft_000065a0_00000000-1.cpp: c1xx: fatal error C1007: unrecognized flag '-Fe' in 'c1xx': how can I resolve this?

not sure. what surprises me is that you are using a compiler for ARM64. are you running windows on arm64 or x64?  can you add the full compilation log to the question body? as well as the output of mex -setup c++ (to see which compilers are installed on your system).

you also could try to open the visual studio solution that comes with MatConvNet and try to build from the Visual studio IDE.

@rinkert I am running windows on x64 how do I fix that to switch from ARM64 to x64

I'm not sure which compilers you have installed right now. To avoid confusion, I suggest to uninstall all compilers (mingw and visual studio) and reinstall them. Make sure you select the c++ desktop development workload for x64/x86 during installation

@rinkert its a bit hard for me to delete and reinstall them is there a way I can change which I am using ive tried a few things but it shows x64 so not to sure where that arm64 is coming from

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/modify-visual-studio?view=vs-2022
